Working with date-times to average values across records in [R]
I have a dataset that looks like this.
# create data frame example
df1 <- data.frame("ckdate" = c("2016-04-28 22:30:00", "2016-05-14 12:00:00", "  
2016-05-15 02:00:00", "2016-05-16 00:00:00", "2016-05-17 03:30:00"),
                  "lab_value" = c(12, 35, 9, 55, 90),
                  "pid" = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
                  )

The goal here is to normailze the date times into 12 hour blocks and then calculate the average "lab_value" within those blocks across patients. Ultimately, so I can make a plot that shows the average lab value at each 12 hour time point. Here is what I have coded up so far
normalize_dates <- function(df){
  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(ckdate = as.POSIXct(ckdate, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>% 
    mutate(hours_since_first = as.numeric(difftime(ckdate, min(ckdate), units = "hours"))) %>% 
    mutate(hours_since_first = hours_since_first %/% 12)
  return(df)
}
df2 <- normalize_dates(df1) # This returns NAs for all differences

There are a number of missing (NA values). So the first thing I am wondering is if difftime can handle NA, and if so is there and na.omit option? Or is there a different way to calculate these differences?
Then for calculating the means I have
# finally, for each 12 hour block, take the average lab_value accross pids
df1 %>% 
  group_by(hours_since_first) %>% 
  summarize(mean_lab_value = mean(lab_value))

But I can't really test this yet because I can't get the 12 hour blocks. I work a lot in R, but have very little experience working with date times, so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

There are missing values in ckdate because, at least in your example, some of your values are not properly cleaned up (you have a line break before the dates).  Probably the rest of your missings are due to incorrect strings that you should fix. You can use df1 %>%  mutate(ckdate = stringr::str_remove(ckdate, "  \n")) to clean it and have it properly converted as date. If you name the dat column as ckdate2, you could filter your dataframe for missing values in said column in order to check why specific values of ckdate didn't got converted to date format.

You have a space in your df1$ckdate file , which blows up all your values.
your input creates, note the \n:
                   ckdate lab_value pid
1     2016-04-28 22:30:00        12   1
2     2016-05-14 12:00:00        35   1
3   \n2016-05-15 02:00:00         9   2
4     2016-05-16 00:00:00        55   2
5     2016-05-17 03:30:00        90   2

cleanup your data like so:
df1 <- data.frame(ckdate = c("2016-04-28 22:30:00", "2016-05-14 12:00:00", "2016-05-15 02:00:00", "2016-05-16 00:00:00", "2016-05-17 03:30:00"),
                  lab_value = c(12, 35, 9, 55, 90),
                  pid = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
)

and the function will work
norm_dates <- function(df){
df %>% 
  mutate(ckdate = as.POSIXct(ckdate, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
         dif = as.numeric(difftime(ckdate, min(ckdate), units = 'hours')) %/% 12)
}
norm_dates(df1)


Thank you. Now that I am aware of this I can see that this dataset is littered with these invisible white spaces. I'm sure it will be easy to find a way to remove them.
